# JWT authentication failing when User class has an entity subclass in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to develop a system that contains customers and vendors and found many common attributes so i decided to use a common user class that has all the authentication information.

Class Diagram:
[class digram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xewS9.png)

I have been having a problem where when i make one of the sub classes an entity so that hibernate creates their table the authentication doesn't work.

Security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager() {
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new DatabaseUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/token").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Token generation functionality:

```
@Service
public class TokenService {

    private final JwtEncoder encoder;

    public TokenService(JwtEncoder encoder) {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }

}
@PostMapping("/token")
    public String token(@RequestBody LoginRequest userLogin) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userLogin.username(), userLogin.password());
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        return tokenService.generateToken(authentication);
    }
```

The custom user details service:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        System.out.println(user + " " + username);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username [" + username + "] not found in the system");
        }
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
```

The customUserDetails is just a class that inherets UserDetails and has an instance variable user that we get the data for the users from.

The user class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "user_table")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User{

    @Id
    private UUID user_id;
    @Column(name = "username",unique = true,nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password",nullable = false)
    private String password;

}
```

The customer class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity(name = "customer") //when i remove this the jwt authentication works
public class Customer extends User{

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

I have tried debugging the token generation function many times and i end up with this exception.
dispatchException:`class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.CaseStatementDiscriminatorMappingImpl$1 cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlSelection (org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.CaseStatementDiscriminatorMappingImpl$1 and org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlSelection are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

but i haven't found any resources leading to the cause of this exception

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by making hibernate do the findByUsername(String username) query automatically instead of making a query using @Query with a native query